# Routing 2 Angular applications, Any URL rewrite?

Tags: url-rewriting, angular6, url-routing, angular-routing, httpd.conf

I have two angular applications, one is for services I have listed, other is admin login and admin uses. 
For 1st Application eg URL: https://example.com/
For 2st Application eg URL: https://example.com/administrator/

If I entered URL like https://example.com/administrator/login, it going to first application, how to navigate URL's like above to my second application.

How to handle this problem?.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use different modules for different tasks. Such as for users redirect to nomal url https://www.example.com  and for admin or administration use https://www.example.com/admin.
.
And use canActivate guard for admin login.

Example... You.can.see my website designed in Angular.

https://www.aman-g.com